# Update several files with msgmerge

Tags: po, msgmerge

I am running the following command to update my po files in two different languages:

```
msgmerge --update src/languages/en_GB.po src/languages/myFile.pot && msgmerge --update src/languages/de_DE.po src/languages/myFile.pot
```

Unfortunately this is not escalable, because in the future I will have more languages. Is there any way to update several files (en_GB.po, de_DE.po... *.po) with a single command?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly passing several files to `msgmerge` but works in a similar fashion:

```
for file in ./src/languages/*.po; do msgmerge --update ${file} src/languages/myFile.pot; done
```